# Using spatial filters in cross-layer filtering by GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, query-layer

I am working with GeoServer, WFS and have querylayer module installed.

I have been trying to extract information around a featured points. For example, the location of all hospitals within 1000 meters of all schools  over a region. I know I can use `DWITHIN` on the layer with hospital information are in, and use `OR` to join multiple `DWITHIN`
`&typeNames=buildings&cql_filter=DWITHIN(geometry,x,y,1000,meters) AND type=hospital`

but this requires me to find out the location of the school manually and construct a `DWITHIN` for every school over the region.

So then I read about cross layer filter [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/querylayer/index.html) and tried this
`&typeNames=buildings&cql_filter=DWITHIN(geometry,collectGeometries(querycollection('buildings','geometry','type=''school'''))) AND type=hospital`

This works perfectly if my layer is small, but my layer consist of data for the whole global, so eventually break on querylayer's limits. So I wanted to limited the region for querylayer and did this
`&typeNames=buildings&cql_filter=DWITHIN(geometry,collectGeometries(querycollection('buildings','geometry','type=''school'' AND BBOX(geometry,A,B,C,D)'))) AND type=hospital` 
Then it stopped working. This does not even output errors, just empty dataset.

If spatial filtering can work inside a querylayer, then how would I use it?

Comment: look in the log at developer level and you will see the actual SQL query being generated along with any error messages. Please add those to the question